# Can't Nick Just Cure Juliette With His Blood?

Tags: grimm

In the last few episodes we've seen that Juliette has

> Somehow transformed into a Hexenbiest.

Shouldn't Nick be able to cure her simply by having her ingest some of his blood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this has now been revealed, namely, that Nick's blood cannot cure Juliette because of the connection between Nick, Juliette, and Adalind.

When Nick finds out that Juliette is a hexenbiest, he goes to visit the new hexenbiest expert that Juliette has been seeing, and he asks her this question. Her response is pretty abrupt, and lacking in details, but the idea seems to be:

- Nick's blood originally stole Adalind's power. Adalind now has Nick's blood permanently in her system, keeping her from using her own hexenbiest side.
- Adalind underwent a complex ritual that restored her power to her.
- Juliette subsequently underwent a ritual to restore Nick's power that was strongly connected to Adalind.

Thus, Juliette is, in effect, "immune" to the neutralizing agent in Nick's blood.

This raises a few other questions, none of which we know the answer to:

- Is it only Nick's blood that won't work? What about, say, Trubel?
- Is *Adalind* also immune to these effects now?

Answer (score 4):

#### Indeed, according to Wesen lore, when a Hexenbiest ingest the blood of a Grimm, they lose their powers but not their skills of Zaubertränke (potion-creation). Since it is possible for a human to become a Hexenbiest through the ingesting of the right potions, the removal of said powers should be as easily done as it was in the case of Adalind.

> If a Hexenbiest ingests the blood of a Grimm, their Wesen part will be destroyed and they will become a normal human. The weakness is common knowledge amongst Hexenbiests, but seems to be closely guarded from outsiders. Since Adalind was visibly shocked when she realized that Nick knew about it, it seems that even Grimms generally don't know about it. A Hexenbiest turned human in this way still retains her knowledge of Zaubertränke and can still create the most dangerous of concoctions. (**REF: Grimm Wikia: [Hexenbiest](http://grimm.wikia.com/wiki/Hexenbiest)**)

**I suspect the question is: Will Juliette tell Nick in a timely fashion or will it be drawn out for suspenseful ratings increases...**

Comment: When, in the history of television, has *anyone* told someone else a relevant secret "in a timely fashion"?

Comment: Ratings. It's the name of the game. They don't care if they entertain you as long as they can sell that airtime...

Comment: I'm curious where that Wikia information was sourced from; because the way I recall the specific episode in question, the implication was that ANY Wesen that ingested a Grimm's blood became human, but that's obviously not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Edenfield has an excellent answer on another person's identical answer (don't know how to link it, sorry). My thoughts on the matter are as follows:

1. > Juliette doesn't have a way of getting Nick's blood without him finding out that she's a newly-made Hexenbiest, and she has not yet had the courage to tell him. Additionally, because his blood was used in the potion that brought back her memory, there might be something about that whole process that now may render his blood ineffective for her. It's interesting to note that both Nick's mother and Trubel are far out of town and quite busy at the moment.
2. > As Claire Coffee recently confided, there is a big showdown a-coming between Adalind and Juliette. Juliette can now give Adalind a run for her money, as her raw powers will be more formidable than Adalind's.

The writers definitely have something up their big magician's sleeves.