# Why wouldnt the Grimm bite work in this situation?

Tags: grimm

We saw a Grimm neutralize a hexenbeast before by stripping her of her powers (Adalind Schade).

Why does this not work for

> Juliette Silverton?

It might have been discussed in some of the episodes but I simply don't remember if there is a reason.

Comment: damn, missed that it was a dupe.

Comment: Hate when they JUST say it cant be done. The saeson is coming to a close and NOBODY on the cast has even suggested getting a vial of Trubbels blod to Juliet or trying with Nicks blood. They just take the word of another hexenbeast... How smart!!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: See the linked original for the final answer, but basically "It won't work because it doesn't work."

---

I'm reluctant to answer this question now, since this is an active area of plot development, but I can at least assure you that as of "Maréchaussée"  no, it has not been explained yet why Nick can't cure

> Juliette

(henceforth referred to as "the Latest Hexenbiest" or "LHB") of being a hexenbiest.

My suspicion is that *he will*, eventually this is how that plot point will resolve itself. At present, he has no idea what has happened, and LHB is scared to tell Nick because they think he'll behead them. To my knowledge, when Nick took away Adalind's powers, LHB had no idea what he was, so it simply hasn't occurred to them to ask.

As far as why none of the other hexenbiesten(?) that know about LHB have mentioned it, I'm less clear. They also may not know the deal -- Sean is only 1/2 hexenbiest, he may not be fully versed in all the lore. I would expect the new hexenbiest mentor lady to know, but she may have an ulterior motive for not spilling the beans.

---

Out of universe, I have a very strong suspicion that the writers are trying to erase that entire "curing Adalind" bit from the show. When then episode first aired, I am pretty sure it was implied that Nick could "cure" *any* Wesen with his blood. They seemed to backtrack from that to only applying to hexenbiest (or I missed something), but for some reason I get a strong feeling that the show runners consider that whole lore element a mistake and want to pretend it never happened.

We'll see if they prove me wrong next week in "Trial by Fire" when, according to the preview, Nick finds out.

Comment: Pretty sure it only worked on a Hexenbiest; they seem to be unique anyway, such as being able to become one instead of having to be born one, as well as the psychic powers

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, complete [response](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81303/41144), Mr. Edenfield! If I may, I'll add to it by offering a couple of thoughts:

1. > Juliette doesn't have a way of getting Nick's blood without him finding out that she's a newly-made Hexenbiest, and she has not yet had the courage to tell him. Additionally, because his blood was used in the potion that brought back her memory, there might be something about that whole process that now may render his blood ineffective for her. It's interesting to note that both Nick's mother and Trubel are far out of town and quite busy at the moment.
2. > As Claire Coffee recently confided, there is a big showdown a-coming between Adalind and Juliette. Juliette can now give Adalind a run for her money, as her raw powers will be more formidable than Adalind's.

The writers definitely have something up their big magician's sleeves.

Comment: I edited your answer, but I didn't realize that this question was a duplicate of [an earlier question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80149/41144). You might want to consider moving your answer over there.

Comment: No worries! I'll do that momentarily.